# Localize Prevalue sources in Umbraco Contour

Tags: umbraco

I have a country dropdownlist in a Contour form that I want to localize. Currently, it uses "Get values from textfile" source type. Is it possible, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and create your own `FieldPreValueSourceType` and look up based on the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName`

Here is an example;
http://www.nibble.be/?p=217

That has been made into a package. 
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/contour-countries